# BizTalk 2010 Output File Routing Based on Element Value

Tags: routes, message, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have an XML to XML map which output beautifully. The issue is we want to route the output based on this one element/field coming into the map (there are 2 different values which can populate the same field).

The problem is the field repeats in the output so the field can't be promoted in the outbound map. We can only seem to get it to output in both locations if we apply a filter to the Send Ports.

I have tried defining a variable based on the field after making the field in the source file both Distinguished and Promoted. I have tried custom receive pipelines as well as send pipelines: currently the closest I come is outputting to both locations.

I know this is child's play for most of you but am stymied myself. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you create a non-repeating element or attribute in the outgoing message that you can promote?

Comment: I cannot modify the outbound scheme--nor even tack the value to another field. If I COULD insert it in the outbound file name I could then sort using a file mask and send to different ports based on that

Comment: Then create an intermediate schema on which you can have that value, and have maps on the send ports that transform it from the intermediate to the final schema, simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a canonical schema that is used internally that has the element used for routing as a promoted property.

Map the incoming message to the canonical schema.

Have your send ports subscribing to the promoted property on the canonical schema.

Have a map on each of your send ports that maps from the canonical schema to the desired outgoing schema.

Comment: My directive now is to NOT use ports subscribing to the promoted property but rather use an Expression to then push the message through a decide shape ad then out the corresponding port. I am getting hung up on the expression for my variable "idNum", which is a System.Int32 variable. The goal is to get the corresponding value for IDNUM in the schema to populate this variable and then use the variable as a means for routing using the decide shape. Any ideas?

Comment: @TBAN65  A rather silly directive.  I'm not clear what you problem is however.   Why not post it as an actual question and add more details?  Do you know that you can add extra branches to the decide shape?

Comment: I know that I can add extra branches. The goal here is to route the message from inside the message box as opposed to using filters on ports as we had in the past. It is simply an exercise, one I must complete, albeit silly.

Comment: @TBAN65 Please post as a new question, show what you have tried, and what does not work about it