# BizTalk routing messages in message box based on field value

Tags: biztalk

I have an exercise I'm working to complete; previously it was de-batching multiple XML messages from one file into individual files. Then I had to route individual files based on a field value which had been promoted using filters on a port. Now the exercise has evolved into taking a multi record XML file, breaking it down to individual XML records, and routing their output to different folders based on a value in one of the fields. The hurdles are as follow:

1. I can't promote a repeating field such as the one I have to use to sort the outbound messages
2. The value of the field is a system.int32; I am sorting on a "equal to or more than 900" and "less than 900" so I need the int type.
3. Beyond simple "idNUm >= 900" I am in over my head with the necessary expression(s).

I have the basic orchestration design down, I am just lacking the expressions. The node I am looking to validate against is IDNum, and occurs in each record.

UPDATE: Still not working

I put in the following in my expression:   IDNumDefined.Customer.IDNum >= 900
and I get "identifier Customer does not exist in "IDNumDefined"; are you missing an assembly reference?" and "unexpected token '>=' "

Ideas? (sorry about not updating question here)

Comment: Is this a practice exercise or for a production app?

Comment: Purely (mandatory) instructional...

Comment: If you are looking at it in an Orchestration you can distinguish rather than promote (but you will still have to debatch as per Pieter's answer).   And then your expression will simply be MessageName.Record.Fieldname => 900.  You only need the one expression as the other can just be the Else

Comment: I tried making the field Distinguished and then set it like above. The result is:   BizTalk_SelfStudy_Week_4_Project.SingleRecordXMLDefined/*[local-name()='Customer' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='IDNum' and namespace-uri()=''] >= 900        ......and now I am getting "unexpected eof". What did I miss here? Your solution sounded like it should have worked.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add details to the question, rather than the comments where it is hard to read and easy to overlook.  P.S.  If you have distinguished it, you should not need to use XPath syntax, just the dot notation as per my comment

Comment: Please see added comments above---looking to have this working by 3pm CST if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't it be => rather than >=     Also, please don't try and impose deadlines.

Answer (score 1):

The debatching has to occur using an Envelope and Body schema.

Once you have this figured out, the debatching can occur using a simple XML disassembler. In the body schema you can quick promote your idNum field by associating a PropertySchema with it.

Once this is taken care of, it is easy to use 2 send ports in order to set your filter subscription(s).

Comment: From comments he made here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674330/biztalk-2010-output-file-routing-based-on-element-value/32684846?noredirect=1#comment77058994_32684846  he needs to do it in an Orchestration rather than port based routing.  But your pattern would be preferable unless their is some other constraint that requires and Orchestration

Comment: Ah, I was unaware this absolutely needed to be executed in an orchestration.